# <br> inside <pre> works in Safari but not Chrome or Edge?

Tags: html, google-chrome, safari, microsoft-edge, networkd3

I am using `<br>` inside a `<pre>` tag (e.g. `<pre>Foo<br>10</pre>`) and this shows correctly in Safari (v12.0.3) as two lines but as `Foo10` in Chrome 72.0.3626.109 (on Mac OS High Sierra) and Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0 (on Windows 10).

[Mozilla Developer Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content) says that `<br>` is "phrasing content" that is allowed in `<pre>`.

The original code is being generated by the R [htmlWidgets](https://github.com/ramnathv/htmlwidgets) and [networkD3](https://github.com/christophergandrud/networkD3) packages and I've tracked the Javascript code that is generating the `<pre>` code to [sankeyNetwork.js](https://github.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/blob/master/inst/htmlwidgets/sankeyNetwork.js) (generates Sankey diagrams).

I've taken the auto-generated html file and stripped out as much as possible to just highlight this issue. When you open this html file and hover of the left bar, you should see "Foo" and "10 ($)" on two lines. In Safari, this works but in Chrome and Edge, it does not. If you hover over the "Bar" bar (no pun intended), you will always see "Bar" and "10 ($)" on two lines because we just use a newline instead of `<br>` in the `<pre>` block.

Here's the html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>

<svg viewBox="0,0,1134,633" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<g transform="translate(20,20)">

<g class="node" transform="translate(0,0)" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
<rect height="593" width="30" style="fill: rgb(31, 119, 180); stroke: rgb(15, 58, 88); opacity: 0.9; cursor: move;">
<title><foreignObject><body><pre>Foo<br>10 ($)</pre></body></foreignObject></title></rect>
<text x="36" y="296.5" dy=".35em" text-anchor="start" style="font-size: 10px; font-family: Arial;">Foo</text></g>

<g class="node" transform="translate(1064,0)" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
<rect height="593" width="30" style="fill: rgb(174, 199, 232); stroke: rgb(85, 98, 114); opacity: 0.9; cursor: move;">
<title><foreignObject><body><pre>Bar
10 ($)</pre></body></foreignObject></title></rect>
<text x="-6" y="296.5" dy=".35em" text-anchor="end" style="font-size: 10px; font-family: Arial;">Bar</text></g>

</g>
</svg>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The simple fix is to change sankeyNetwork.js and replace `<br>` with `\n` and I will raise this on the networkD3 GitHub page.

Any idea as to why Chrome and Edge are not rendering the `<br>` tag correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I've reproduced your issue on my side. And after testing, I've found the issue maybe because of the  tag.

Here is my testing code.

```
    <svg width="100" height="100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" style="cursor: help;">
            <!--<pre>Foo<br>10 ($)</pre>-->
            <title>
                <pre>Foo<br>10 ($)</pre>
            </title>
        </circle>
    </svg>
```

[image: inside title]

[image: outside titlte]

You could see from the screenshot that br inside  and outside it shows differently. So I think maybe it is the issue.

I've checked MDN document https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/title,
but there seems no explanation. So strange.

Comment: Interesting. Which browser is this result for? Chrome?

Comment: On both Chrome and IE. For testing, I think that maybe it is becasue of the browser behaviour. I also test this in IE, while br works well in IE. So I guess maybe on most latest browsers, it all behaviour like br not working in titile.